# SonataAdmin memory on random files

Tags: php, memory, symfony, symfony-sonata

I have configured SonataAdmin bundle but and i've got a random memory problem when i intend to load admin/dashboard ,

Here is my 2 entities which contains Sonata CRUD :

```
namespace Jade\ReveBundle\Admin;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;

use Jade\ReveBundle\Entity\Thematique;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Validator\ErrorElement;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;

class ProduitAdmin extends Admin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('titre')
            ->add('description')
        ;
    }

    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {
        $datagridMapper
            ->add('titre')
            ->add('description')
        ;
    }

    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
            ->addIdentifier('id')
            ->add('titre')
            ->add('description')
        ;
    }

    public function validate(ErrorElement $errorElement, $object)
    {
        $errorElement
            ->with('titre')
                ->assertMaxLength(array('limit' => 32))
            ->end()
        ;
    }
}


namespace Jade\ReveBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Validator\ErrorElement;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;

class ThematiqueAdmin extends Admin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('titre')
            ->add('description')
        ;
    }

    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {
        $datagridMapper
            ->add('titre')
            ->add('description')
        ;
    }

    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
            ->addIdentifier('id')
            ->add('titre')
            ->add('description')
        ;
    }

    public function validate(ErrorElement $errorElement, $object)
    {
        $errorElement
            ->with('titre')
                ->assertMaxLength(array('limit' => 32))
            ->end()
        ;
    }
}
```

Anyone i've got an idea of the problem ?
Thx for your answer

Comment: "random memory problem", please elaborate and provide error messages if applicable

Answer (score -1):

If the error is "*PHP Fatal Error: Allowed memory size of xxxx bytes exhausted...*", then try to increase PHP memory limit. Sonata is using Doctrine ORM and entities may consume a lot of memory.
A lot of informations are stored in memory in profiler in dev mode, too.

File web/app_dev.php and web/app.php:

```
<?php 
ini_set('memory_limit','128M'); //or some other reasonable value
...
```

or in php.ini:

```
memory_limit = 128M
```

Comment: A list or datagrid cannot consume so much memory. Increasing the limit is not a real solution.

Comment: Author of this question did not write his value of the memory_limit. So it's solution if his value is too low.